# C# WPF reset tab order of controls at runtime

Tags: c#, wpf, telerik, wpf-controls, accessibility

I'm developing a WPF application where I have various controls (both out of the box WPF controls and some Telerik controls). In one of the sections of the application is a grid with various items that can be dragged around to rearrange the position of the item on the grid in relation to other items.

When loading up the application the default tab order goes through all the various controls as expected and once it reaches the grid section it sequentially tabs through each control from top left down to the bottom right - as expected.

Then after I drag one of the items within the grid to another location all of the items shuffle along however when I try to tab through the items it does not recognise the new order of the tiles.

My question is, how am I able to reset the tabbing order on the controls to reflect the latest position of them within the grid?

Notes:

- The controls which I am using are built for drag and drop.
- The control is called a RadTileView (Telerik control), the sub-items which I am dragging and dropping are called RadTileViewItems
- I don't believe that their is anything within the Telerik documentation that addresses this specifically
- Surely this isn't a Telerik only problem; as it is possible to create custom drag and drop functionality within WPF so this would possibly be an issue there too.
- I am currently implementing MVVM.

Comment: do you set the TabIndex property of the controls when dragging around?

Comment: You might have a look at this implementation on CodeProject (it's not WPF, but you may find the principle applies): http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/8406/Automatic-Runtime-Tab-Order-Management-for-Windows